# How to add annotations and comment in Pdfs in a Django web application

Tags: reactjs, angular, pdf, annotations, pdf.js

I am working on a Django web application where I need to **build a pdf viewer** (preferably within the web app interface, but a new tab is also fine). I need to be able to **add annotations (adding shapes, comments) to the pdf** and save them/use the modified document further.
However,I am fairly new to web application development.

I found this PDFTron's sample version tool( they offer tools at price) to make his happen: https://github.com/PDFTron/webviewer-custom-ui.

The sample tool works using React and Node.js and launches as an independent server operation from the localhost. How can I integrate it in my web application so this can be triggered from the website itself?

My research gave me an idea that building my own API for commenting and annotating pdfs in the web application could be a good solution. But I have never had my hands on API development before. I am very confused as how to achieve this. Am I going in the right direction?

Should I follow the PDFTron's tool way or try to develop my own API? Any guidance or suggestions are highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!